# protractor - wait for element / page load / angular

Tags: angularjs, webdriver, protractor, webdriverwait

I have wait like this:

```
browser.waitForAngular();
const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element), 10000);
```

I always get a timeout. I tried to change time - 10/20/30 s but it didn't work.
Visually page is visible, all inputs and buttons are visible but I get a timeout. 
**I log to the page like http://user:password@domain.com**

Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Increase timeout for jasmine:

```
// protractor.conf.js
module.exports = {
    framework: 'jasmine2',
    allScriptsTimeout: 500000,
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 500000,
        showColors: true
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Your page seems to be non-angular page so if you wait for angular it will keep waiting and ultimately time out. Check if your page is non-angular.

Note: To check if you have a non-angular page: View source and verify if

- Application declared using ng-app directive
- check for ng-model, ng-repeater attributes in the code.

Answer (score -1):

You are wrong with the method of the expectedConditions. You should try with:

```
browser.waitForAngular();
const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element), 10000);
```

Sorry for my english!.